# How do I resize various dialogue boxes that ask for passwords, user inputs etc?

Tags: resize, dialog

Here is a screen-shot of what I want to resize. On Ubuntu 11.10, this kind of dialogue were little short by length. That looked good. Is there a way to do so by digging in the system files or by changing configs for compiz?

[image]